# How to trigger an action from one view controller to another in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

How would I go about changing the a UILabel property in another view controller?

I have `#import "SecondViewController.h"` imported in the FirstViewController.m file and then

I have the following in a method in FirstViewController

```
-(IBAction) someAction {

    SecondViewController *objV1 = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];

    objV1.secondViewControllerLabel.alpha = 0.2;

NSLog(@"someAction");

}
```

when someAction is called nothing happens to the UILabel in the SecondViewController.

also, in this example both first and second view controllers are in another view controller called MainViewController. So, they are both onscreen at the same time.

thanks for any help.

Comment: If you do alloc, it just creates new instance of your class and will not reflect on actual class which you have presented. How are you presenting secondViewController and where?

Comment: Your SecondViewController's view is not loaded yet. To load this view you need to access the SecondViewController's view. [SecondViewController view] then try it. Or present that view and set the value

Comment: in this example both first and second view controllers are in another view controller called MainViewController. So, they are both onscreen at the same time

Comment: @Anil [SecondViewController view]; gives a warning that "Class method  '+view" not found(return type defaults to id"

Comment: SecondViewController *obj; [obj view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you tell us, it would seem that you need to set the "embeded view controllers" as childs of the parent View Controller.

```
[mainViewController addChildViewController:childViewController];
[childViewController.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.childContainerView addSubview:childViewController.view];
[childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

This is very powerful, because you can forward IBActions from the `mainViewController` to their child...

```
[mainViewController childViewControllers]
```

Returns an array of them, and also take a look at

```
– shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods
– shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods
```

So your child get automatically informed about the rotations of their parent.

To answer your question, you could do something like:

```
// In Parent View Controller
- (IBAction) anAction:(id) sender
{
    for (CustomChildController *child in self.viewControllers) {
        [child handleSomeAction];
    }
}
```

Check out what the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) say for more details.

Answer (score 1):

@Goles answer will work, but if you specifically want to trigger the change from FirstViewController.m you need to pass in a reference to SecondViewController somehow.

So you could do it with a custom init that takes a reference to your second viewcontroller as a parameter, or create a property on your FirstViewController that you can set from outside, which would be something like this:

FirstController.h:

```
@interface
..
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *second;
...
@end
```

FirstController.m:

```
@implementation
@synthesize second
```

In your parent ViewController you would create both the child view controllers, then:

```
ViewController1.second = ViewController2;
```

Then your action method would become:

```
-(IBAction) someAction {
    self second.secondViewControllerLabel.alpha = 0.2;
NSLog(@"someAction");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since in the secondViewController, secondViewControllerLabel has not been created yet, 'objV1.secondViewControllerLabel.alpha' will have no effect. Ideally, you should create a NSNumber property called labelAlpha in the secondViewController, set that property in the firstViewController, and then in the viewDidLoad of the second controller, add this line ::

```
self.secondViewControllerLabel.alpha = self.labelAlpha;
```

This will work for you.

Comment: As a hack, just so you understand, if you explicitly call the viewDidLoad of the secondViewController, after you initialize it in the firstViewContoller, it will work too. So just adding objV1.view;, after you initialize, will call viewDidLoad of the 2nd controller and it will work

Comment: thanks. how would you explicitly call the viewDidLoad of the secondViewController?

Comment: Just accessing the view property of the viewController will call the viewDidLoad, so just adding this line 'objV1.view;' will call the viewDidLoad

Comment: access the seconViewController view property like [seconViewController view] ...:)

Comment: @DhruvGoel if I add     objV1.view; I get a warning saying that "property access unused and getters should not be used for side effects"

Comment: @Anil would you mind writing the syntax for [SecondViewController view]; everything I'm trying doesn't work... thanks